# Bottom Bracket Size for Specialized Roubaix Elite C2 2009

Tags: road-bike, bottom-bracket

I think my bottom bracket has worn and I would like to replace it.  I was looking at the Shimano 105 BB.  [BikePedia](http://www.bikepedia.com/quickbike/BikeSpecs.aspx?Year=2009&Brand=Specialized&Model=Roubaix%20Elite%20C2&Type=bike) lists the size as 68mm, which is fine, but there seems to be another dimension.  I can get `68 x 109 mm` or `68 x 118 mm`.  Is it possible to work out which size I need without removing the current BB?

**update**
I'm not sure which of the below answers is correct.  In the end I bought a SM-BB6700 Bottom Bracket BC1.37 which worked fine (techdocs [here](http://techdocs.shimano.com/media/techdocs/content/cycle/SI/Ultegra/SI_1LM0A_001/SI-1LM0A-001-ENG_v1_m56577569830671289.pdf)).

Comment: This is a good question - but too specialised (sic). How about generalising the question - "How to calculate the bottom bracket size?" - then it would be more use for more people.

Comment: @Unsliced: I think this question is acceptable as is, but your question could be valuable on its own. Why don't you ask it?

Answer (score 1):

It is best to remove your current bottom bracket to check, but as a rule of thumb, a triple (3 gear) front crank uses a 118mm. A double (2 gear) front crank uses a 109mm.

Answer (score 0):

It's nominally the distance from one end of the shaft to the other, with the cranks removed (though there can be a 1-2mm variation).  You can rig a caliper to measure it with the cartridge in place, or you can "eyeball" it with a ruler.

But once you have the cranks removed it's not that big a deal to remove the cartridge.  (Still a little tricky to measure with the cartridge removed, though.)